# View Count of MongoDB object will not increase

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ejs

I am new to programming and have recently updated my user.js schema to include the following to try and capture the view count of a blog object.

```
   title: String,
   image: String,
   body: String,
   viewCount: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
   },
```

I am storing data in MongoDB. I am attempting to create a sidebar on a website that would show most viewed blog posts.

I run this route on my index page.

```
// INDEX ROUTE
router.get("/blogs", function (req, res) {
  var perPage = 10;
  var pageQuery = parseInt(req.query.page);
  var pageNumber = pageQuery ? pageQuery : 1;
  var noMatch = null;
  if (req.query.search) {
    const regex = new RegExp(escapeRegex(req.query.search), 'gi');
    Blog.find({name: regex}).skip((perPage * pageNumber) - perPage).limit(perPage).sort({"created": -1}).exec(function (err, blogs) {
      if (err) {
        throw new Error(err);
      }

      Blog.count({name: regex}).exec(function (err, count) {
        if (err) {
          throw new Error(err);
         }

        if (err) {
          console.log("ERROR!");
        } else {
          if (blogs.length > 1) {
            noMatch = "No blogs match that query, please try again";
          }
          Blog.find({}).sort({viewCount: -1}).limit(5).exec(function (err, topBlogs) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
            } else {
              res.render("blogs/index", {blogs: blogs, topBlogs: topBlogs, current: pageNumber, pages: Math.ceil(count / perPage), currentUser: req.user, noMatch: noMatch, search: req.query.search});
            }
          });

        }
      });
    });
  } else {
    Blog.find({}).skip((perPage * pageNumber) - perPage).limit(perPage).sort({"created": -1}).exec(function (err, blogs) {
      if (err) {
        throw new Error(err);
      }

      Blog.count().exec(function (err, count) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("ERROR!");
        } else {
          Blog.find({}).sort({viewCount: -1}).limit(5).exec(function (err, topBlogs) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
            } else {
              res.render("blogs/index", {blogs: blogs, topBlogs: topBlogs, current: pageNumber, pages: Math.ceil(count / perPage), currentUser: req.user, noMatch: noMatch, search: false});
            }
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }
});
```

And I set up a in ejs the follow to display it.

```
                <h3 id="topposts">Top Posts</h3>
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <% topBlogs.forEach(function(topBlog, i){ %>
                    <li class="list-group-item"><a class="header" href="/blogs/<%= topBlog._id %>"><%= i+1 %>.  <%=topBlog.title%></a></li>
                     <% }); %>
                </ul>
        </div>
```

The output works and the 5 top links display however only the first 5 blog posts created since I implemented the change to my blog schema show up and even if I view a page a dozen more times in relation to the first 5 blog posts created the rank doesn't change. I tried to view them in the database and all of the objects have zero as a viewCount. Am I missing an action or step to change the viewCount value of the object?

Comment: Please show us all relevant code. Show us the front end JS that updates the view count, too.

Comment: @SamCurry Hey Sam, I think that is part of the problem, I don't have any front end code that updates view count, is that why I am having the issue in the first place?

Comment: Yes you clearly are not updating any document in your database if this is your entire code thats relevant to the model.

Comment: @tomslabbaert Yes I must be missing this, i've been trying to locate some set of code now based on yours and Sam's feedback do you know of one?